# Extract domain name from string

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking how to extract a domain name from a URL in a column in my PowerBI report.
I tried to use that formula:

```
DOMAIN = LEFT([URL],FIND("/",[URL],9)-1)
```

But it says

> The search Text provided to function 'FIND' could not be found in the given text.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to do this in DAX or M?

Comment: I tested the above formula on a couple of URLs and it seems to be working fine...Can you share a couple of sample URLs where it is failing?

Answer (score 2):

In DAX it would be [SEARCH](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/search-function-dax) which has the same syntax as the Excel FIND function:

```
SEARCH(<find_text>, <within_text>[, [<start_num>][, <NotFoundValue>]])
FIND(find_text, within_text, [start_num])
```

So it will be

```
DOMAIN = LEFT([URL],SEARCH("/",[URL],9)-1)
```

Update: there is a find function in DAX, I didn't realise it, always used Search! Search supports wildcards find doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula depends on the URL containing a "/" after the http section. I think it's failing because, there is no "/" after the first few characters. So, you may have to improvise, based on the URL you see. For example, if the domain ends with .com, you could use:

```
DOMAIN = LEFT([URL],FIND(".com",[URL],9)+3)
```

The type of URL you have becomes important here. Hope this helps.